# how to load blade view with tcpdf laravel 5?

Tags: pdf-generation, laravel-5, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf using laravel 5 and https://github.com/elibyy/laravel-tcpdf

Is there a way to load view and passing data to the view?

something like

```
  $pdf = new TCPDF();  
  $pdf -> SetPrintHeader(false); 
  $pdf -> SetPrintFooter(false); 
  $pdf -> loadView('pdf.invoice',$data); // 
  $pdf -> Output(storage_path().'/pdf/file.pdf', 'I');
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
$pdf->writeHTML(view('your.view')->render());
```

However, the functionnalities of writeHTML() method are limited, see TCPDF documentation.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
    $view = \View::make('myview_name',compact('dynamic_data'));
    $html = $view->render();

    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf::SetTitle('Hello World');
    $pdf::AddPage();
    $pdf::writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf::Output('hello_world.pdf');
```